# Nuget : Additional computed target framework(s)

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

In nuget.org, when you check any package there are 2 types of framework.
[image]

What is the difference between Compatible target framework and additional computed target framework?

Answer (score 19):

A *compatible target framework* is directly derived from the *Target Framework Monikers* (TFMs) of a NuGet package. In your screenshot, the NuGet package targets `net45` and `netstandard2.0` - you will find these entries in the corresponding `.csproj`/`.nuspec` file.

The *additional computed target frameworks* are all kind of frameworks which are implicitly supported due API compatibility. For example every project targeting `netstandard2.0` is compatible to `netstandard2.1`, as the APIs of .NET Standard 2.1 completely contain all APIs of .NET Standard 2.0.
The same is true for `net45`: an application/assembly targeting .NET Framework 4.5 will automatically be supported on .NET Framework 4.6, 4.7, etc.

Microsoft announced this [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-compatible-frameworks-on-nuget-org/).

Comment: For example, I don't understand why https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4#supportedframeworks-body-tab supports .net 5. 
Code written for .net 3.1 is not de facto compatible with .net 5 because of the many breaking changes : cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0. So why is nuget saying that this lib is compatible with .net 5 ?

Comment: Well, I think that focusing on breaking changes has a certain bias because it doesn't take into account the sheer mass of APIs that remained stable/untouched/compatible. Doing such a fine-grained decision cannot be done without proper analysis. Just think about a .NET Core 3.1 assembly using a deprecated API in an unused method. When referencing and running this assembly in a .NET 5 context, the JIT compiler will not call the deprecated API (because the method is unused), so there won't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure to understand. Does "Computed additional target framework(s)", means "you can try this package with that target framework and see if it works" ?  So for exemple, without testing IdentityServer4 with net 60, there's no way to be sure it works fine with net 60. Is that correct ?