# What does Dependencies mean in Visual Studio Nuget Manager?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

While installing a package via Nuget Manager in Visual Stuido, it always show the detail information of this package. Look at the Dependencies for RestSharp.
It says

> .NETFramewokr,Version=v4.7.1.
> System.Text.Json (>=7.0.2)

Previously, I thought this RestSharp 110.2.0 can only be installed in project with .net framework 4.7.1. But I find that it can still be installed in project with .net framework 4.6.2.

What does Dependencies mean here? How can I know all the .net frameworks the current RestSharp 110.2.0 support?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

In my opinion, I don't deem there is any mechanism that was computing the compatibility of the API.

Wether you can install the package successfully to your project is no matter with the APIs.

For example, a package in the nuget gallery which named TiTLibrary:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TiTLibrary

[image]

You know this package will be unable to installed in net framework 4.6.2.

But I can easiliy make it be able to install without any API match.

Steps:

1, Rename the 'titlibrary.1.3.0.nupkg' to 'titlibrary.1.3.0.zip'.

2, Open it, remove the signiture file, and then add a folder named net462 under the lib directory:

[image]

3, Search a dll file, the dll of your RestSharp package is also no problem, rename it as TiTLibrary.dll.

4, Put the dll file to the net462 folder in the nuget zip:

[image]

5, rename the 'titlibrary.1.3.0.zip' to 'titlibrary.1.3.0.nupkg'.

After the above steps, you will be able to install the package to the net462 project(On my side, I am using Local path as nuget source):

[image]

In this situation, you will know there is no any computation step of API compatibility.

The mechanism is still the answer I posted before, I just clarify more about this.

**Original Answer:**

I can explain to you why this happens:

Besides the description in the Visual Studio package dependencies, you can also go to the nuget gallery to get a more intuitive:

[Nuget Gallery | RestSharp 110.2.0 Frameworks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/110.2.0#supportedframeworks-body-tab)

[image]

From the Frameworks tab, you can see that the package support net6.0, net7.0, netstandard2.0, net framework 471

This also expressed in the Visual Studio package dependencies:

[image]

Which need to pay extremely attention is the net standard version 2.0, which means wildly support in many framworks:

[.NET Standard version 2.0 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0)

You can see that the .net framework 462 was supported:

[image]

Comment: Hi  Bowman, thanks for your answer. I have some different findings. It says that if a nuget library is compatible with .net framework 4.7, the library author will also check what .net framework api it has invoked inside .net framework 4.7.  If the author finds that all the api this library has invoked also exist in .net 4.6 and 4.5, then this library is computed compatible with .net 4.6 and 4.5.

Comment: @RobinSun How do you know this, is there any offcial documents? If yes, you can post an answer to end your question.:)

Comment: Please refer to this post here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72373931/nuget-additional-computed-target-frameworks

Comment: @RobinSun I don't think so, see my updated answer. I even don't need any code, I am able to make any package successfully installed in any target project(Your original question content is asking download, wether you can able to use the apis is another thing. That required namespace and it's contains.). no need any compute steps, no need api compare. If you say compare, that should mean compare whether there is related target dll in nupkg. :)

Comment: @RobinSun If the mechanism is what you thought, it will be a very long time for the package pack and package install. The author check the apis one by one or msbuild check them one by one, I don't think it is correct. If I misunderstand, please feel free to let me know. I think the mechanism is what I said before. I even don't need code leave alone the APIs match.

Comment: Thanks for your time. What you are doing for TiTLibrary is a kind of 'compute', isn't it?

Comment: @RobinSun That based on your understanding of 'compute'. Anyway, based on the frameworks of the package in nuget gallery, you will get the compatibility details of the package. If you deem the above mechanism as 'compute', then I can say the frameworks tab is based on that mechanism.