# How can I find where a specific SDK dependency is coming from in a dotnet core solution that fails to build because of it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, .net-core-2.1

I'm working on a .Net Core 2.1 codebase (it needs upgrading but time constraints have prevented that so far).

I added a Nuget package, FFMpegCore, which had a dependency on `System.Text.Json` 7.0.1. The solution built locally in VS2017, but when using `dotnet build` on the build server it failed with errors about `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` not being compatible with `netcore2.1`.

This all ok, I first downgraded the package to a version using `System.Text.Json` 6.0.1 (to find that that's also not supported by 2.1), but then to one using 5.0.1, which itself has a dependency on `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` 5.0.0, which [looks compatible](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/5.0.0).

I'm now seeing this error on the build server:

`/home/build/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe/6.0.0/buildTransitive/netcoreapp2.0/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.targets(4,5): error : System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe doesn't support netcoreapp2.1. Consider updating your TargetFramework to netcoreapp3.1 or later. [/opt/build/develop/site/site.csproj]`

Visual Studio now shows FFMpegCore as only having the 5.0.0 dependency for unsafe via `System.Text.Json`, but it looks as though there's still something left over from the incompatible versions. Is there a way to find out what or where it is? Or could it be some kind of caching problem?

**Update**

I read [this article](https://andrewlock.net/stop-lying-about-netstandard-2-support/) and it seemed related, so tried going back to a much earlier version of FFMpegCore which didn't use `System.Text.Json` (Newtonsoft instead, which is used everywhere else in the same solution) - but same build errors.

Then tried switching branch to the version of the code without any FFMpegCore at all, which was built ok a few weeks ago and is running on the server, and .. same build errors.

Seemed to be something persisting in the build environment, so tried:

`dotnet nuget locals all --clear`

..and the build is working again, both for the previous code and for that using the Newtonsoft-dependent version of FFMPegCore, so the fix was not to use `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` at all with 2.1.

Comment: I would try this: https://kb.froglogic.com/coco/howto/visualstudio-verbosity/ <- it's helped me in the past when the build was failing but the error was just that a dependency failed.

Comment: Thanks, good call, but `dotnet build -v diag` didn't seem to give anything obviously-useful - just told me that it was going to output an error, then output the same error.

Comment: net standard regulation still works, your situation comes from root dependency package configuration. Take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your situation:

[image]

This situation is expected.

The issue you encountered comes from the targets file under 'buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0' folder of the package:

```
<Project InitialTargets="NETStandardCompatError_System_Runtime_CompilerServices_Unsafe_netcoreapp3_1">
  <Target Name="NETStandardCompatError_System_Runtime_CompilerServices_Unsafe_netcoreapp3_1"
          Condition="'$(SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings)' == ''">
    <Error Text="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe doesn't support $(TargetFramework). Consider updating your TargetFramework to netcoreapp3.1 or later." />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Normally(I mean if it is not in this folder), This error is emitted unconditionally for all target frameworks, unless the `$(SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings)` property is set. It means that this error will be emitted for all projects that reference this package, regardless of their target framework.

But since it is in the netcoreapp2.0 folder, it will only affect netcoreapp2.0 projects/packages.

This is no matter with the net standard compatible mechanism. The package configure a limitation in it, and if you match the limitation, it pop out the configured error, this is just what it is.

You just need to set your csproj file like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>xxx</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FFMpegCore" Version="5.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And it works:

[image]

Your situation comes from dependency package configuration. Package compatible is not a mystery thing, and the checking steps is just based on the structure of the package content, nothing else.

Take a look of this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76926018/6261890

I can even make a package compatible with any framework of .net, I even don't need any code, I just need to match the structure it needs. So net standard just give you a framework, whether it suitable for you is another things. It just like a convention/constraint for people, and people follow this regulation.

Generally, net standard 2.0 package should suitable and compatible for your net core 2.1 app.

Reason:

[Net standard 2.0 supported frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0#select-net-standard-version)

[image]

The situation you encountered comes from the limition of the root package configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this - the older FFMpegCore package had a few issues related to `System.Drawing.Common` so went back to the 5.0.0 version, configured as you suggest, and it now builds, deploys, and runs with no problems - detailed answer much appreciated!